# Making a "Trending/Most Viewed Articles" in Vue

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

First time working with Vue and and making a vue app using the wordpress rest api.

What I want to do is make some sort of a "Trending/Most Viewed articles" component based on the number of views.

In wordpress, there's a plugin like WP-PostViews that stores the post views in a meta field and then you can query the posts based on that count.

Is it possible to do something like that in Vue? What would be the best approach? Maybe do a "axios.post" on click? I'm sorry I'm not very familiar with Vue

Answer (score 0):

Made a quick example for you with axios.
You should replace URL with your API.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    articles: []
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .then(response => {
        this.articles = response.data
      })
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js"></script> 
<div id="app">
  <h2>Articles:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="article in articles">
      {{article.title}}
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

*Description:*
Fetching resource (API) in mounted hook, so everytime component loads, will fetch for your articles
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Getting posts is not an issue. However, the post view plugin counts the "views" on each page reload, however, since my app is all vue + vue router, there's no page reload.

Comment: Ok, then you should make API call before/on page load, to count that page view. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-before-navigation